# How to make the embed change when a user reacts on the message in discord.py rewrite?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

How do I make the embed description change when a user reacts with `▶` or `◀`?
This is the code I currently am using, -

````
@client.command(aliases=['commands', 'info', 'cmds'])
async def help(ctx):
    embed1 = discord.Embed(title=f"Everyone/Fun Commands-",description=f"```!vx userinfo [Member]```\n"
                                                                       f"**- Shows the info of the user mentioned.**\n\n"
                                                                       f"```!vx ping```\n"
                                                                       f"**- Shows the ping of the bot.**\n\n"
                                                                       f"```!vx help```\n"
                                                                       f"**- Shows a list of all commands.**\n\n"
                                                                       f"```!vx avatar [Member]```\n"
                                                                       f"**- Shows the Avatar of the mentioned user.**\n\n"
                                                                       f"```!vx hello```\n"
                                                                       f"**- Shows a hello message.**\n\n"
                                                                       f"```!vx bye```\n"
                                                                       f"**- Shows a bye message.**\n\n"
                                                                       f"```!vx mention [Member]```\n"
                                                                       f"**- Mentions the user in the server and also in DMs.**\n\n"
                                                                       f"```!vx dankmeme```\n"
                                                                       f"**- Sends a dank meme generated from r/dankmemes2.**\n\n"
                                                                       f"```!vx dm [Member] [Message Content]```\n"
                                                                       f"**- DMs the Message content to the Member mentioned.**\n\n"
                                                                       f"```!vx embed [Message Title] [Message]```\n"
                                                                       f"**- Sends an embed message in the channel.**\n\n", color=0x40cc88)
    embed1.set_thumbnail(url='https://cdn.probot.io/agdJCAIfLR.png')
    await ctx.send(embed=embed1)

    embed2 = discord.Embed(title="VX Commands-", description=f"```!vx prices```\n"
                                                             f"**- Show the official VX Price list.**\n\n"
                                                             f"```!vx portfolios```\n"
                                                             f"**- Shows the list of portfolios of VX Members.**\n\n"
                                                             f"```!vx order [Product]```\n"
                                                             f"**- Creates a ticket for you to order a product.**\n\n"
                                                             f"```!vx apply```\n"
                                                             f"**- Sends a Dm regarding info to apply for VX.**\n\n", colour=0x40cc88)
    embed2.set_thumbnail(url='https://cdn.probot.io/agdJCAIfLR.png')
    await ctx.send(embed=embed2)

    embed3 = discord.Embed(title="Mod Commands", description=f"```!vx kick [Member]```\n"
                                                             f"**- Kicks the member mentioned.**\n\n"
                                                             f"```!vx ban [Member]```\n"
                                                             f"**- Bans the member mentioned.**\n\n"
                                                             f"```!vx unban [MemberName#1234]```\n"
                                                             f"**- Unbans the member tagged.**\n\n"
                                                             f"```!vx clear [No. Of Messages]```\n"
                                                             f"**- Clears the number of messages specified.**\n\n"
                                                             f"```!vx nuke```\n"
                                                             f"**- Nukes the channel**\n\n"
                                                             f"```!vx register [Member] [Portfolio URL]```\n"
                                                             f"**- Adds the Member's Portfolio to the !vx portfolio command.**\n\n"
                                                             f"```!vx close```\n"
                                                             f"**- Closes the ticket created by a member.**\n\n"
                                                             f"```!vx spam [Member]```\n"
                                                             f"**- Spams the user in the channel and also in his dms, Only use when required.**"
                                                             f"```!vx add [Member] [Role]```\n"
                                                             f"**- Gives the role mentioned to the member.**\n\n"
                                                             f"```!vx remove [Member] [Role]```\n"
                                                             f"**- Removes the role mentioned from the meber.**", colour=0x40cc88)
    embed3.set_thumbnail(url='https://cdn.probot.io/agdJCAIfLR.png')
    embed3.set_footer(text=f"Commands requested by {ctx.author.display_name}", icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed3)
````

Also, I want to clear the reactions of the user when the user reacts on the message.
Moreover, I want to display the 3rd embed(Mod Commands) to only a user who has the permission - administrator.
Any Help is appreciated.

EDIT - I know how to change an embed normally, I just cant figure out how to change it when the author adds a reaction...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's help you. [Docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=reaction#discord.on_reaction_add):

```py
@bot.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
    for role in user.roles:
        # administrator role name = 'test_role'
        if role.name == 'test_role':
            # if user is administrator
            # do something
            break
    else:
        # if user is not administrator
        # and add emoji ▶ or ◀ for any message
        if reaction.emoji == '▶':
            # if user add reaction emoji - ▶
            # do something
            pass
        elif reaction.emoji == '◀':
            # if user add reaction emoji - ◀
            # do something
            pass
```

Answer (score 0):

I am also figuring out the same thing.
I can now take user reactions but not clear them so they have to press twice(once to clear and then to react)
and moreover all the embeds edit on being sent
Here is my code for reference:

```
def check(reaction, user):
        return user == author and str(reaction.emoji) in ["➡","⬅"]

    help_list=[help_embed,server_embed,greet_embed,fun_embed,music_embed,utility_embed]
    count=0
    help_msg=await ctx.send(embed=help_list[count])
    await help_msg.add_reaction("⬅")
    await help_msg.add_reaction("➡")
    
    while True:
        reaction, user = await self.bot.wait_for('reaction_add',check=check)
        print(str(reaction))
        if str(reaction.emoji) == "➡":
            count+=1
            if count>len(help_list)-1:
                count=0
            await help_msg.edit(embed=help_list[count])
            await help_msg.add_reaction("⬅")
            await help_msg.add_reaction("➡")
    
        elif str(reaction.emoji) == "⬅":
            count-=1
            if count<0:
                count=len(help_list)-1
            await help_msg.edit(embed=help_list[count])
            await help_msg.add_reaction("⬅")
            await help_msg.add_reaction("➡")
```

Note: help_list is just a list of embeds.

Thank you!

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/28776662)

Comment: I am sorry but this answers half of the question this code takes user input for reactions. @Chris