# Discord.py help command (react to edit message)

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make a help command that if you react it changes the message (edits the message) to the next page (I have 4 help pages and a default page (showing what numbers = what page)).

I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62566038/how-to-make-the-embed-change-when-a-user-reacts-on-the-message-in-discord-py-rew) about this but it was an arrow reaction and I couldn't figure out how to change it to 0 1 2 3 4 reactions.

```
0 - help page
1 - fun commands
2 - Emoji commands
3 - admin commands
4 - misc commands
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Here I'm using a variable (i) to keep track of the page number. You'd initially send an embed (page 0) and grab the message object (msg).

```
def reac_check(r, u):
   return msg.id == r.message.id and u!=self.bot.user and r.emoji in ['1','2','3']
i = 0
while True:
     try:
        reaction, user = await self.bot.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=20.0, check=reac_check)
        em = str(reaction.emoji)
     except TimeoutError:
         print("caught")
         break #we exit the loop
      
     if user!=self.bot.user:
        await msg.remove_reaction(emoji=em, member=user)

     if em == '1':
        #edit message with embed of page 1
     #other cases go here
```